# Login page appears after while on homePage

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, web

I am new on web development, I am planning to show my login-page after while on homePage even  after any click.

I am using node js as backend and angular2 as front-end  ?any suggestion any links may be usefull on the above  .

Thanks alot

Comment: This doesn't make much sense. Can you explain better what you are trying to do?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display the login page after a long time, like their session times out and displays the login page?

Comment: No , it's not realted to seesion timeout , let's say after 3-5 seconds  or after any click on home page web site

Comment: Is this what you want? 1: User navigates to home page. 2: a timer of 5 seconds starts in the background. 3: when the timer finishes, the user is automatically navigated to the login page

Comment: **yes , exactly**

Answer (score 0):

This will solve your problem !

```
<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href='form2.html'},5000);</script>
//5000=5seconds
And for home page add only '/'

<script>setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="/"},3000);</script>
```